# Can I say "I was gifted" in the sense of gratitude?

Tags: word-choice

Can I say

> In India, I was gifted in so many unexpected ways

in the sense of immense gratitude, like "I received so much", "I got so many gifts and blessings"?

Comment: This is a case where avoiding the passive voice would improve your writing.

Comment: Just use "I was blessed in so many unexpected ways"

Comment: I am withdrawing my answer of the transitive use of the verb gifted - by popular (or unpopular in my case - lol) vote.

Answer (score 2):

Although "gifted" has that meaning, In BrE we usually use it to mean possessing innate abilities. The [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gifted) says

> Having exceptional talent or natural ability.

If you want to say you were given presents, this way

> In India, I was rewarded in so many unexpected ways.

implies a sense of gratitude too. Alternatively

> In India, people showed their appreciation in many unexpected ways.

Comment: It can be used that way in US English too, by the way.